# Automate a command that needs to be run with thousands of different arguments

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, shell, automation, large-files

In my project I need to upload a big file (~250GB) to remote server, and then run a script to load the file into mysql.
The problem is, if I load the single file it will take too long time. So I have to split the file into small trunks and run 10-20 processes simultaneously in multiple terminals. If I split each file ~2MB, it will take me 100,000 times operation.Then I have to run like

```
ruby importer.rb data_part01_aa.csv
ruby importer.rb data_part01_ab.csv
ruby importer.rb data_part01_ac.csv
.
.
.
```

in each terminal, wait for them to end, and run the next.

Is there any method that can automate this process? Any shell scripts that can continue doing the job when the previous one is finished?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In shell you can try:

```
for i in *.csv
do
    ruby importer.rb $i.csv
done
```

The previous one can be written as one-line as follow:

```
for i in *.csv; do ruby importer.rb data_part01_aa.csv; done
```

Eventually, it can take some time to start running if the arguments are too many.  In such case, you can try with `find`:

```
find . -name '*.csv' -exec ruby importer.rb {} \;
```

However, the previous command will search recursively in every sub-directory.  To make it run for the current directory only, you will have to run:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' -exec ruby importer.rb {} \;
```

In every example given, the commands will be run sequentially.  Instead of `*.csv` you can play with different patterns (i.e. `a*.csv`, `b*.csv`, `[ab]*.*csv`, etc.), or you can try another loop:

```
for j in $(echo {a..q})
do
    find . -name "data_part01_$j?.csv" -exec ruby importer.rb {} \; &
done
```

Where `echo {a..q}` generates a sequence of letter from *a* to *q*, which seems to follow the names of your files.  The key in the last example is the *&*, which leaves the process in background, in the last example, there will 17 process running simultaneously.  If you do not want them simultaneously, then you just need to remove the ampersand *&*.